# How to determine if Java heap memory is set too high?

Tags: java

How can I tell if the heap memory of 1 Java application is too high by jvm monitoring? Currently our Java application heap memory is set to 16G, but judging from experience, this value is set too high and I want to convince other colleagues to lower this value for saving resources, but I don't know how to visually show that the memory setting is too high through monitoring.

This problem, I think the more difficult point is that memory is not like CPU, how much is actually used and how much is set by Pod, there is an obvious contrast, Java heap memory set to 16G, the startup directly occupies 16G, and regardless of whether the heap memory is set to 8G or 16G, I understand that it is nothing more than a matter of triggering the garbage collection frequency, I can't justify lowering the memory to 8G, or 4G I can't prove that by reducing the memory to 8G or 4G, the program will run smoothly and not trigger an OOM exception.

Comment: Would any visual tool help you for this analysis?
I personally recommend VisualVM: https://visualvm.github.io/
In my personal case it helped me to detect a part of the process that was generating a java heap memory error. The tool shows you the CPU and memory usage, perhaps it can be a visual guide to set the maximum resources used by an application

Comment: *Java heap memory set to 16G, the startup directly occupies 16G*  Not necessarily.  You can set an initial value (-Xms) and a limit (-Xmx).  Unless you mean that your application startup is so memory-intensive it will immediately drive heap size to the limit.

Comment: the only option to determine proper limits is to perform thorough performance testing, the question is whether it will recoup the cost of 8Gb memory.